# Python - separate duplicate objects into different list

Tags: python, duplicates, unique

So let say I have this class:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

And now I have these objects:

```
s1 = Spam((1, 1, 1, 4))

s2 = Spam((1, 2, 1, 4))

s3 = Spam((1, 2, 1, 4))

s4 = Spam((2, 2, 1, 4))

s5 = Spam((2, 1, 1, 8))

s6 = Spam((2, 1, 1, 8))

objects = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]
```

so after running some kind of method, I need to have two lists that have objects that had same `a` attribute value in one list and the other objects that had unique `a` attribute.

Like this:

```
dups = [s2, s3, s5, s6]
normal = [s1, s4]
```

So it is something like getting duplicates, but in addition it should also add even first occurrence of object that shares same `a` attribute value.

I have written this method and it seems to be working, but it is quite ugly in my opinion (and probably not very optimal).

```
def eggs(objects):
    vals = []
    dups = []
    normal = []
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.a in vals:
            dups.append(obj)
        else:
            normal.append(obj)
            vals.append(obj.a)
    dups_vals = [o.a for o in dups]
    # separate again
    new_normal = []
    for n in normal:
        if n.a in dups_vals:
            dups.append(n)
        else:
            new_normal.append(n)
    return dups, new_normal
```

Can anyone write more appropriate pythonic approach for such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group together the objects in a dictionary, using the `a` attribute as the key. Then I would separate them by the size of the groups.

```
import collections

def separate_dupes(seq, key_func):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for item in seq:
        d[key_func(item)].append(item)
    dupes   = [item for v in d.values() for item in v if len(v) > 1]
    uniques = [item for v in d.values() for item in v if len(v) == 1]
    return dupes, uniques

class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    #this method is not necessary for the solution, just for displaying the results nicely
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Spam({})".format(self.a)

s1 = Spam((1, 1, 1, 4))
s2 = Spam((1, 2, 1, 4))
s3 = Spam((1, 2, 1, 4))
s4 = Spam((2, 2, 1, 4))
s5 = Spam((2, 1, 1, 8))
s6 = Spam((2, 1, 1, 8))
objects = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]

dupes, uniques = separate_dupes(objects, lambda item: item.a)
print(dupes)
print(uniques)
```

Result:

```
[Spam((2, 1, 1, 8)), Spam((2, 1, 1, 8)), Spam((1, 2, 1, 4)), Spam((1, 2, 1, 4))]
[Spam((1, 1, 1, 4)), Spam((2, 2, 1, 4))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add an `__eq__` method to `Spam`, defined as

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.a == other.a
```

then you can do this quite simply with something like

```
# you can inline this if you want, just wanted to give it a name
def except_at(elems, ind):
    return elems[:ind] + elems[ind+1:]
dups = [obj for (i, obj) in enumerate(objects) if obj in except_at(objects, i)]
normal = [obj for (i, obj) in enumerate(objects) if obj not in except_at(objects, i)]
```

Comment: This seems to throw me `TypeError: 'Spam' object is not subscriptable
` I wonder if it's on my end, will look into it when I have time on your `except_at` function.

Comment: My apologies! I passed the wrong variable into `except_at`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), these are the keys that are common to more than one:

```
import collections

common = [k for (k, v) in collections.Counter([o.a for o in objects]).items() if v > 1]
```

Your two lists, now are

```
[o for o in objects if o.a in common], [o for o in objects if o.a not in common]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, if the list of objects isn't too large, is to sort the list of objects and then apply `groupby` to it to get the duplicates. To sort the list we supply a key function that extracts the value of the object's `.a` attribute.

```
from operator import attrgetter
from itertools import groupby

class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Spam({})'.format(self.a)

s1 = Spam((1, 1, 1, 4))
s2 = Spam((1, 2, 1, 4))
s3 = Spam((1, 2, 1, 4))
s4 = Spam((2, 2, 1, 4))
s5 = Spam((2, 1, 1, 8))
s6 = Spam((2, 1, 1, 8))

objects = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]

keyfunc = attrgetter('a')

dupe, unique = [], []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(objects, key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc):
    g = list(g)
    target = unique if len(g) == 1 else dupe
    target.extend(g)

print('dupe', dupe)
print('unique', unique)
```

**output**

```
dupe [Spam((1, 2, 1, 4)), Spam((1, 2, 1, 4)), Spam((2, 1, 1, 8)), Spam((2, 1, 1, 8))]
unique [Spam((1, 1, 1, 4)), Spam((2, 2, 1, 4))]
```